# Replace matches between files with number sequence

Tags: r, bash, loops

I have two text files:

FileA has three columns:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3  
111111 111111 0  
222222 222222 0  
333333 333333 0  
444444 444444 0  
666666 666666 0
```

FileB has one column (no header):

```
222222  
444444  
555555  
666666
```

I want to replace content in columns 1 and 2 of FileA if it matches content in FileB. I want the replacement be a sequence of negative numbers, starting at -4.

Desired output:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3  
111111 111111 0  
-4 -4 0  
333333 333333 0  
-5 -5 0  
-6 -6 0
```

The actual length of FileA is ~500k and FileB is 80.

An R or bash solution would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this assumes two columns have the same values

```
$ awk -v c=-4 'NR==FNR {a[$1]; next} 
               $1 in a {$1=$2=c--}1' fileB fileA 

Col1 Col2 Col3  
111111 111111 0  
-4 -4 0
333333 333333 0  
-5 -5 0
-6 -6 0
```

**Explanation** 
save the first file values in array `a`.  If the first field of fileB is in the array `a` replace first and second fields with the counter `c` and decrement the counter.  Print all the lines (updated or not).

Answer (score 1):

With base R you can do it like this.

```
FileA[] <- lapply(FileA, function(x){
  i <- match(FileB$Col1, x)
  if(all(!is.na(i))) x[i] <- -seq_along(i) - 3
  x
})

FileA
#    Col1   Col2 Col3
#1 111111 111111    0
#2     -4     -4    0
#3 333333 333333    0
#4     -5     -5    0
#5     -6     -6    0
#6     -7     -7    0
```

**Data.**

```
FileA <- data.frame(Col1 = c(111111, 22222, 333333, 444444, 555555, 666666),
                    Col2 = c(111111, 22222, 333333, 444444, 555555, 666666),
                    Col3 = 0)
FileB <- data.frame(Col1 = c(22222, 444444, 555555, 666666))
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked on the toy example, but not in my actual files. Perhaps this is because my actual files are not sorted?

Comment: @oneill If the dataframe `FileA` is not sorted, substitute `i <- sort(match(FileB$Col1, x))` for the code line in the answer. I believe it will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick with a nested loop:

```
equalities <- apply(filea, 2, function(x) x %in% fileb)
result <- filea
replacement <- c(-4:-99)

for( i in 1:ncol(result)) {
  result[,i] <- ifelse(equalities[,i], "toreplace", result[,i])
  nbmatches <- 1
  for( j in 1:nrow(result)) {
    if("toreplace"==result[j,i]) nbmatches <- nbmatches + 1
    result[j,i] <- ifelse("toreplace"==result[j,i], replacement[nbmatches],result[j,i])
  }

  }
result
    Col1   Col2 Col3
1 111111 111111    0
2     -5     -5    0
3 333333 333333    0
4     -6     -6    0
5     -7     -7    0
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason this took a long time and I had to kill the job - perhaps because there are so many lines in my file (>500k)